# Stress testing hardware

Tags: windows

I recently bought a bunch of new hard drives, servers and other items. What is a good way to stress test the hard to ensure it won't crash in the first week?

I've read and heard that if hardware is to break it will be within the first week typically

Comment: Hardware can fail at any time.  I had a hdd last 2 and half years into a 3 year warranty.  Your better off buying hardware with a good warranty and keeping good backups of your data then trying to force a failure.

Answer (score 2):

Install a new game. Actually most games will push your computer more than most apps.

If you want to beat up your CPU then try [Prime95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime95). Try some encoding with Handbrake.

AIDA64 is something else you could give a try. I think you can only try it for 30 days. Actually most HD die right when you least expect it and usually when its full of all your important data :/

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed and configured your machines correctly, you shouldn't be too paranoid about hardware failure. You can never sure though, that's why you should backup your data. Stress testing new hardware is generally not something most people do. If you stick to well-known, reputable hardware your chance of it being faulty is less. Stress tests, stability tests, performance benchmarks, etc. are usually used for overclocking purposes or troubleshooting faulty hardware.